# PowerShell Get-Counter works with one-element array but not more

Tags: powershell

This works:

```
$Counters = @('\Memory\Pool Paged Bytes')
Get-Counter -Counter @Counters
```

And so does this:

```
$Counters = @('\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time')
Get-Counter -Counter @Counters
```

But the following throws an error

```
$Counters = @('\Memory\Pool Paged Bytes')
$Counters += '\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time'
Get-Counter -Counter @Counters
```

Error text:

```
"Get-Counter : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time'.
At line:3 char:12
+ Get-Counter <<<<  -Counter @Counters
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Counter], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetCounterCommand"
```

Can someone explain why? I suspect I'm not understanding PowerShell arrays.
I know I can probably work around this by directly creating a CSV string, but I don't want to do it that way, I'd rather add to the array using the += operator, or understand why that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Oops, I had the syntax wrong (was getting confused about '$' vs '@' I guess).  The following works.

```
$Counters = @()
$Counters += '\Memory\Pool Paged Bytes'
$Counters += '\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time'
Get-Counter -Counter $Counters
```

Comment: Strangely, if I add quotes around the last "$Counters", I get a different and very misleading error "Unable to connect to the specified computer or the computer is offline."